# Jest beforeEach no longer works after using Globals

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am testing an `addHours` function:

```
function addHours(date, hrsToAdd) {
    date.setHours(date.getHours() + hrsToAdd);
    return date;
}
```

It passed an ordinary `describe...it...` test with `beforeEach`:

```
let testDateObj;
beforeEach(() => {
    testDateObj = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
});
describe('Test add hours', () => {
    it('addHours(date, 0) should return current hour', () => {
        expect(addHours(testDateObj, 0)).toEqual(testDateObj);
    });
});
```

However, the `beforeEach` caused error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setHours' of undefined` after changing the test to use Globals:

```
describe('test add hours', () => {
    test.each`
        func                         | parameter            | expected
        ${addHours} | ${[testDateObj, 0]}  | ${testDateObj}
    `('returns $expected when $func($paramter)', ({ func, parameter, expected }) => {
        expect(func(...parameter)).toStrictEqual(expected);
    });
});
```

I tried to define a `testDateObj` without `beforeEach` and it worked. Any idea how to make the Globals test work with `beforeEach`?

Comment: Why would the _function_ be part of the table of tests?

Comment: What do you mean? Which function?

Comment: addHours, the function you're testing. That'll be the same in all test cases, it doesn't belong in the table.

Comment: Why does it not belong in the table? I'm trying to test if `addHours(testDateObj, 0)` equals to `testDateObj`, in this example.

Comment: Or I could test if `addHours(testDateObj, 3)` equals to `new Date('December 17, 1995 06:24:00')`

Comment: Because, again, it's the same in every test case. And why jam all the params into one thing? `expect(addHours(start, toAdd)).toEqual(expected)` would be a much more readable test body.

Comment: I see your point. The example isn't a good test. But why does `beforeEach` not work in this case?

Comment: Because the `beforeEach` runs _just_ before each, at test _execution_ time, whereas the table is evaluated at test _definition_ time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is there a way I could reset `testDateObj` before each test?

Comment: Why do you need to? Create a _different start date_ in the table for each test.